# In the ES6 Class below, why does goFast() work?

Tags: ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to learn more about ES6 and saw this class in a tutorial. Why does `goFast()` work without a `function` keyword in front of it? Is this a new shorthand for functions in classes, or…?

```
class RaceCar extends Car { //inheritance
  constructor(make, topSpeed) {
    super(make); //call the parent constructor with super
    this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
  }

  goFast() {
    this.currentSpeed = this.topSpeed;
  }
}

let stang = new RaceCar('Mustang', 150);
stang.printCurrentSpeed();
stang.goFast();
stang.printCurrentSpeed();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a new shorthand for functions in classes

Yes; see [the ES6 draft](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html) for the definitions of the various relevant parts of the grammar:

> ClassBody : ClassElementList
>   ClassElement : MethodDefinition
>   MethodDefinition : PropertyName ( StrictFormalParameters ) { FunctionBody }

Comment: @SpencerKillen: No, it works in object literals too.